# Game-changer or game changer … Hyphenation

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

This is my first question. 
I already did a lot of research but didn't find a specific answer that helps me with this.
I know there are three forms (closed, open and hyphenated) in combining words.
With prefixes it seems rather clear, but what about nouns or verbs?
So is it "game-changer" or "game changer"… "mind-changer" or "mind changer"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92961/hyphenation-or-blending) of possible interest.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are using the word.  Sometimes looking at the dictionary is helpful as well to see if it is first an approved hyphenated word. Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. (e.g., It was one of those game-changer throws by outfield that saved the game).

Comment: That makes sense – thanks for pointing out the connection to the modified noun.